# Matplotlib: plotting line chart set line type, scale and customized colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am newbie with Python and Matplotlib, and I'm trying to do a line plot with the following code:

```
cov = np.array([164430.5, 84322.6, 83595.6])
p2 = np.array([92118.2, 30813.8, 36428.7])
p5 = np.array([16033.3, 15940.9, 16555.1])
s = np.array([315262.9, 176823.4, 182933.4])
ax = np.array([1, 8, 32])

plt.plot(ax, cov, 'r--', ax, p2, 'bs', ax, p5,'g^', ax, s, 'y*')

plt.show()
```

So far, I see the plot working well, but I do not know how can I do the following:

1. Join the symbols with a smooth line
2. Change the X axis to see only 1, 8 and 32 but also with the same distance between them.
3. Change the scale to a logaritmic.
4. Apply to each line, some customized colors in hexadecimal.

Could you guide me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. plt.plot(ax, cov, 'r-', ax, p2, 'bs-', ax, p5,'g^-', ax, s, 'y*-') 3. plt.yscale('log'). You should look at the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/), it has multiple examples to help guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question to help someone else if they need it!:

> Join the symbols with a smooth line

Change `'r--'` for `'r-'`.

> Change the X axis to see only 1, 8 and 32 but also with the same distance between them.

Finally, I didn't this, but something approximately is using this: `plt.xticks(ax, (1, 8, 32))` . The only thing I coudn't do is to keep them equidistant.

> Change the scale to a logaritmic.

`plt.yscale('log')`

> Apply to each line, some customized colors in hexadecimal.

`color = '#FF7373'`

I have also changed the way to write everything, because it was clearer for me. So here is all together:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cov = np.array([164430.5, 84322.6, 83595.6])
p2 = np.array([92118.2, 30813.8, 36428.7])
p5 = np.array([16033.3, 15940.9, 16555.1])
s = np.array([315262.9, 176823.4, 182933.4])
ax = np.array([1, 8, 32])

plt.xticks(ax, (1, 8, 32))

line1, = plt.plot(ax, cov, '*-', label='cov', color = '#4F81BD') # blue
line2, = plt.plot(ax, p2, 'o-', label='p2',color = '#C0504D') # red
line3, = plt.plot(ax, p5, '^-', label='p5', color = '#9BBB59') # green
line4, = plt.plot(ax, s, 's-',  label='s', color = '#FF7373') # pink

plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```